# how to check which Intent started the activity?

Tags: android

I have many activities. Each one of them has an intent which refers to the same activity. Is there a way to find out which intent started the activity?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

try as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setClass(A.this,Receiveractivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Uniqid","From_Activity_A");  
A.this.startActivity(intent);

Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setClass(B.this,Receiveractivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Uniqid","From_Activity_B");  
B.this.startActivity(intent);

Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setClass(C.this,Receiveractivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Uniqid","From_Activity_C");  
C.this.startActivity(intent);
```

and in onCreate of main Activity:

```
//obtain  Intent Object send  from SenderActivity
 Intent intent = this.getIntent();

  /* Obtain String from Intent  */
        if(intent !=null)
        {
        String strdata = intent.getExtras().getString("Uniqid");
         if(strdata.equals("From_Activity_A"))
         {
         //Do Something here...
         }
         if(strdata.equals("From_Activity_B"))
         {
         //Do Something here...
         }
         if(strdata.equals("From_Activity_C"))
         {
         //Do Something here...
         }
         ........
        }
        else
        {
            //do something here
        }
```

use `putExtra` for sending Unique key from Each Activity to identify from which Activity intent is Received

Comment: Why not a custom action instead of extra data?

Answer (score 5):

You didn't provide any context, so here's one general approach.

Put an extra into each Intent type, like a unique int or String:

```
intent.putExtra("Source", "from BroadcastReceiver");
```

and use:

```
String source = getIntent().getStringExtra("Source");
```

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution that doesn't involve passing data from one Activity to another.

Use startActivityForResult in your calling activity to start the activity:

```
ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(this, new Intent(this, MyActivity.class), 0, null);
```

In the callee Activity, you can use the following code to detect the calling activity.

```
    if (getCallingActivity() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, getCallingActivity().getClassName());
    }
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.