# Use Enum for checking condition

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, enums

I am working on an application in which there are some fragment classes, which can be open by two ways in the application. The first way is **Main Flow** , the second way is through the **Navigation Drawer**.

So when the fragment is called from the Navigation Drawer than it will perform some task, and if it's call from the Main Flow than it will perform another task.

How can I check the context? Is there possibility through the use of **Enum class**.

**Note:**

1. I don't want to send the hardcoded value through the Intent.

Comment: Don't think it's possible without putting and intentExtra. Similar'ish question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529529/how-to-check-which-intent-started-the-activity

Comment: everything depends on how you start the fragment in different situations.

Comment: some one told me to use Enum.. so that's why i ask this question....

Comment: enum would also be a hardcode value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you should avoid using `enum`s in Android environment. Prefer to use [`@IntDef`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/IntDef.html), [`@StringDef`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/StringDef.html). The main reasoning behind this is the waste of resources. Enums take much more memory.

As Colt McAnlis shows [in this perfmatters episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hzs6OBcvNQE) enums take 13x more space on rather trivial example.

Secondly, what you want to achieve may be done via `Intent`s or `Bundles`, passing a boolean value from one component to another.